# react-table column width does not get adjusted after manipulating its show property

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am showing a list of columns using a react table. I have a drop down as a first column which shows list of columns that needs to be shown/hidden. But The problem is whenever a column is being hidden by making show as false ,the table width does not get adjusted.

[image]

This is after I have hidden all the columns using settings icon , there is a lot of space after status column. I want to avoid it . I am using width property to set width for each column. I want the width to get auto adjusted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using react-table? If so I found this example. I think this is  what you are looking for.

[react-table simple table](https://codesandbox.io/s/03x3r0vx1l)

Comment: Yes . I am using react-table. In my case columns are not getting aligned properly when a column is hidden when its show property is made false

Comment: Did the example help you? If not then could you post a sample of your code. Id be glad to take look at it.

Comment: got it fixed by removing width property and replacing it with minWidth

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding!